# Can we have two class definitions in same file/package in java? class Node and class Node<T>

Tags: java

I am just curious to see if we can at all have two different class definitions of same class name, one with generic type and another without generic type:

```
class Node {}
```

and

```
class Node <T>{}
```

in the same file or in the same package in Java.

Comment: Learning core lessons about type erasure will answer the question.

Comment: Have you been curious enough to try it?

Comment: I did , and it gave error "the type node is already defined"

Comment: IMHO this ain't such a bad question since you *can* do this in C++ with templates. Upvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not possible. `Node <T>`, for *any* `T` collapses to `Node <java.lang.Object>` upon compilation (this is called *type erasure*), which would then be indistinguishable from `Node`.

So really `Node <T>` and `Node` are the same thing and your compiler ought to complain that your source file contains a duplicate class.

In this, and many other respects, Java generics are the poor cousin of C++ templates where the above *would* be possible (through default template parameters and template specialisation).

Answer (score 1):

### Generics in Java are implemented using a technique called erasure.

**All type parameter information is erased from the run-time type system**. Asking an object of a parameterized type for its class will return the class object for the raw type (eg. List for an object declared to be of type List. A consequence of this is that you cannot at runtime ask if an object is an instanceof a parameterized type or simple type.

**so the answer to your question is no its not possible.**

Read more on erasure [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)